# Get records that satisfy all conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
A | B | C | D | E | F
a   1   2   1  4   001
b   4   3   1  4   001
c   1   1   1  4   001
b   1   3   1  4   001
d   1   2   1  4   001
a   1   2   1  4   002
b   4   3   1  4   002
b   1   1   1  4   002
```

Table 2

```
A | B | C | D | E
a   1   2   1  4
b   4   3   1  4
c   1   1   1  4
d   1   2   1  4
```

OutPut :

```
F    |  D  
001    1
```

So columns A, B, C, D, E and F are all columns that specific conditions in them. Table 1 is the table with data that needs to be compare to data in table2. If all records in different columns except `F` match from Table1 to the records in Table2, only those records should be selected in the output.

Edit:

Only 001 from column F is displayed because it has all the 4 rows with the same values in the same columns as given in Table 2. Records with value 002 in column F are not selected because they do not all the rows in table 2. 
Something I tried-

```
select count(A) over(Partition by A,B,C,D,E,F) as rw,* 
into #temp1 
from Table1

select sum(rw) as sm, F 
from #temp1 group by F

select F 
from #temp
where sm = (select count(A) from Table2)
```

One of the issues with this logic is that 002 can have 2-3 duplicated rows which might result in the count being equal to the count of rows in table2 .

Comment: have you attempted this at all yet? Sounds like you just need multiple conditions in your JOIN

Comment: @ADyson I am a little lost on how to approach this. If I put multiple conditions on the join it won't help because I want only those values in column F that satisfy all records in table 2.

Comment: are you saying you want to compare records in different _rows_, rather than different _columns_? I think you could have written the requirement a lot more clearly.

Comment: are you saying you want to compare records in different _rows_, rather than different _columns_? I think you could have written the requirement a lot more clearly.

Comment: @ADyson Okay so maybe i wasn't clear. So, see the values in all columns for 001 has 5 rows and all values in all the columns for the 5 rows matches to all the values in all the columns for all the rows in table 2 which is why only 001 is selected. 002 is not selected because it doesnt have all the records that table 2 has. hope this makes sense

Comment: It does I think. You should probably edit your question to make that clear. And then, although this kind of SQL is not my expertise, you might be able to benefit from researching CTE (common table expressions) or maybe window functions

Comment: It does I think. You should probably edit your question to make that clear. And then, although this kind of SQL is not my expertise, you might be able to benefit from researching CTE (common table expressions) or maybe window functions

Comment: @ADyson I am not sure how a CTE would help here. I actually tried to count the rows partitioning it based on the different columns but the issues is that, there could be duplicates which wont give me the right records when I sum them. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Like I said, I'm far from expert on this type of query, it's not similar to anything I have to do in the databases I work with. But if you make your question clearer there's a better chance of it being re-opened and someone with detailed expertise being able to help. It's also always worth mentioning what you have already researched and tried (ideally with a code sample) so that people can see you didn't just ask others for help without making any effort yourself - as unpaid volunteers ourselves we generally don't appreciate questions like that.

Comment: @ADyson Do I have to do anything to re-open the question? Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just edit it to be better quality, as you've just done (thanks). Editing will move it up the list of questions, so it's likely to be back on the front page (at least for the tagged topics). Then it's up to those viewing it, and with the required [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to vote to re-open it. A single re-open vote will also cause the question to appear in the moderation queue for re-opening, so that more people will review the merits of doing so. Be patient.

Comment: I have a solution that resulted in SELECT DISTINCT F,D,E, FROM T1 WHERE F='001'. In your logic above, E should be included as it is distinct in both sets.

Comment: @RossBush This is only a sample set...your query will not solve the issue as I want to find a dynamic way to find the output. Your query is only applicable to the above dataset. I cannot post the entire dataset as it is pretty large.

Comment: The text above is the output of my query, dynamic is the only way to do it.

Comment: I was just saying that I think E should have been an included column.

Comment: @RossBush I am sorry I have lost you completely. If people can remove this off of hold maybe you can post what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample creation code to run in SQL Fiddle:

```
create table t1 (
    A varchar(1),
    B int,
    C int,
    D int,
    E int, 
    F int);
create table t2 (
    A varchar(1),
    B int,
    C int,
    D int,
    E int);
insert into t1 VALUES 
    ('a', 1, 2, 1, 4, 1),
    ('b', 4, 3, 1, 4, 1),
    ('c', 1, 1, 1, 4, 1),
    ('b', 1, 3, 1, 4, 1),
    ('d', 1, 2, 1, 4, 1),
    ('a', 1, 2, 1, 4, 2),
    ('b', 4, 3, 1, 4, 2),
    ('b', 1, 1, 1, 4, 2);
insert into t2 VALUES 
    ('a',1,2,1,4), ('b',4,3,1,4), ('c',1,1,1,4), ('d',1,2,1,4);
```

Join the two tables together, selecting only column A and F, with a distinct clause to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.A, t1.F
FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.B = t2.B
    AND t1.C = t2.C
    AND t1.D = t2.D
    AND t1.E = t2.E;
```

Count the total number of rows for each F:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t1.A) AS countNum, t1.F
FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.B = t2.B
    AND t1.C = t2.C
    AND t1.D = t2.D
    AND t1.E = t2.E
GROUP BY t1.F
```

Filter out only the ones that have matches for all of a,b,c,d, with a Having clause:

```
SELECT t1.F
FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.B = t2.B
    AND t1.C = t2.C
    AND t1.D = t2.D
    AND t1.E = t2.E
GROUP BY t1.F
HAVING count(DISTINCT t1.A) = 4
```

If you don't know how many different constraints there are beforehand, you can replace the '4' with a count on the number of constraints in t2:

```
SELECT t1.F
FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.A = t1.A
WHERE t1.B = t2.B
    AND t1.C = t2.C
    AND t1.D = t2.D
    AND t1.E = t2.E
GROUP BY t1.F
HAVING count(DISTINCT t1.A) = 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) FROM t2)
```

(That could also be put into a CTE, I believe.)

The last block there only selects column F, but I don't know whether you could unambiguously select any other column since, e.g. what if there was the row ('d', 1, 1, 1, 4, 001) in t1? What should be displayed?

Depending on your needs, you could throw that last block into a subquery, to be used in something like `WHERE F IN (above query)`.

Comment: Wont this give 001 & 002? 002 should not be pulled in because it does not satisfy all the rows in table 2.

Comment: Hnm, you're right. I'll edit the post to answer the question when I get the chance to.

Comment: @qwerty I edited my answer; does this fit your needs now?